# An expansion for $\ln^2\Gamma(x+1)$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, cauchy-product

I was reading *Irresistible Integrals* by Victor H. Moll, where I encountered the following Taylor series expansion of $\ln\Gamma(1+x)$
$$
\ln\Gamma(1+x)=-\gamma x + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k \zeta (k)}{k}x^k.
$$

I am looking for the Taylor series for $\ln^2\Gamma(1+x)$. I guess that maybe I can just square the result I already have, like this
$$
\begin{align}
\ln^2\Gamma(1+x)
&= \left(-\gamma x +\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k \zeta (k)}{k}x^k\right)^2\\
&= \gamma^2x^2 -2\gamma \sum_{k=2}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k\zeta(k)x^{k+1}}{k}+ \left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k \zeta (k)}{k}x^k\right)^2.
\end{align}
$$

If this is true, how can I square the sum? I think Cauchy product can help, but that will be very complicated and requires more manipulations which are way too much for me as I am new to the manipulations of zeta function.

Any help?

Comment: $(\sum_{n=a}^b a_n)^2= \sum_ {k=a}^b a_k\sum_{n=a}^b a_n= \sum_{n=a}^b \sum_{k=a}^b a_n a_k$, but this is just basic factoring. Do you know about [Cauchy Products](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)?

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S=\left(\sum_{n=a}^b a_n\right)^2= \sum_ {k=a}^b a_k\sum_{n=a}^b a_n= \sum_{n=a}^b \sum_{k=a}^b a_n a_k$$
but this is just basic factoring. Do you know about [Cauchy Products](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)?

I will work on this a bit more. Simply use the formula. This also works for other powers.

$$S= \left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k \zeta (k)}{k}x^k\right)^2= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k \zeta (k)}{k}x^k \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n \zeta (n)}{n}x^n= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k \zeta (k)}{k}x^k\dfrac{(-1)^n \zeta (n)}{n}x^n= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+n} \zeta(n)\zeta (k)}{kn}x^{k+n} $$

Comment: I had thought of reindexing. Thanks.